# Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexRelease'. finished with non-zero exit value 2

Tags: android, facebook-sdk-4.0, paypal

I have just added the paypal sdk and the following error occurred when building:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexRelease'. com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 2
```

I have seen many threads suggesting that I add

```
    multiDexEnabled true
```

but this does not work on api 18 and below. Also, It brings other errors with my facebook sdk.
Is there any other way I can handle this error?
Here's my build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
repositories {
mavenCentral()
}
android {
compileSdkVersion 22
buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.edwardokoth.myapp"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 22
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
    }
}

}

repositories { mavenCentral() }

dependencies {
compile files('libs/Parse-1.9.4.jar')
compile files('libs/ParseFacebookUtilsV4-1.9.4.jar')
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: 'Parse-*.jar')
compile fileTree(include: 'ParseFacebookUtilsV4-*.jar', dir: 'libs')
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'
compile 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.+'
compile 'commons-io:commons-io:+'
compile 'fr.avianey.com.viewpagerindicator:library:2.4.1@aar'
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
compile 'com.h6ah4i.android.materialshadowninepatch:materialshadowninepatch:0.6.3'
compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:1.3.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.1.0'
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.6.0'
compile 'com.oguzdev:CircularFloatingActionMenu:1.0.2'
compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.1'
compile 'com.paypal.sdk:paypal-android-sdk:2.12.4'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Check if there are libraries conflicts ( same library but different version ). In this case i supose you should exclude support library module from Facebook SDK.

```
compile ('com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.6.0'){
        exclude group: 'com.google.android', module: 'support-v4'
    }
```